# Using the Apple IKImagePicker_Class in a java application

Tags: java

I was able to use the IKImagePicker_Class in my cocoa with very little trouble but I am wondering how hard would this be to get working in a java application.  Has anyone tried this?  Have they had any luck?  How hard was it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Rococoa](http://rococoa.org). It's work in progress, but does let you access Cocoa classes from Java with not too much pain.